# How to run Microsoft Bot Framework on CentOS

Tags: service, server, centos, portability, botframework

I have a CentOS VPS and a Microsoft Bot Framework program. Is there a way that I can deploy the bot onto the CentOS VPS? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BotFramework has libraries written for NodeJs and .Net (including .Net core that works on Linux platforms) out of the box, and it has REST API that can be utilized from any language on your platforms that allows doing http/s requests.

So, the simplest way for you: write your bot on NodeJs and deploy it to CentOS. There're plenty of examples on BotFramework site how to create bots in NodeJs.
https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/overview/